# Showing that $p(x,y)= |1/x - 1/y|$ is a metric for set $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis

I believe I have confirmed all the other properties (MS1 through MS4) for determining that $p(x,y)$ is a metric. However I'm unsure about the second property because of the set $\mathbb{R}^+$.
I have done the following for definiteness/uniqueness property:

> If $x=y$, then it implies that $p(x,x)=0$.
>
> Let $p(x,y)=0$ then $|1/x-1/y|= 0$. Then $1/x - 1/y = 0$, therefore, $x=y$. Hence $p(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$.

But is this correct considering the set in question?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: the set (0,infinity) doesn't somehow negate the uniqueness property? I got the idea that p(x,y) can't be 0 then.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think it should? A metric for a set $\mathbb{R}^+=(0,\infty)$ just means that $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$, not $p(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^+$ (maybe this is your source of confusion?).

Comment: @projectilemotion ok got it, i automatically made that assumption for p(x,y) which is incorrect